# How to add Microdata to an Offer details page?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

We have an offer detail page like so:

```
Get a Free Toy

Bring home a limited edition toy only $11.90 with any purchase.

Offer period:

18 February 2017 – 20 April 2017
```

Is this the correct way of adding the schema tags to it?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

    <h2 itemprop="name">Get a Free Toy</h2>

    <p itemprop="description">Bring home a limited edition toy only $11.90 with any purchase.</p>

    <h4>Offer period:</h4>

    <p itemprop="validThrough">18 February 2017 – 20 April 2017</p>

</div>
```

My problem is it's an offers detail page but I'm not sure where to put the `Offer` itemtype within it or is it even needed?

Answer (score 1):

The `Product` is only for describing the thing. It doesn’t say anything about getting/offering it. That’s also the reason why you can’t have the `validThrough` property on `Product` (so your snippet is not correct).

If it’s the same toy in all cases, you could use the `Product` item to describe this toy (name, manufacturer, etc.). Then you can use its [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers) property to add an `Offer` for it:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <!-- properties about the Product -->
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <!-- properties about the Offer -->
  </div>
  <!-- properties about the Product -->
</div>
```

If you don’t need a `Product` item, simply provide the `Offer` item on its own:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
</div>
```

---

For the offer period, you can’t use [`validThrough`](http://schema.org/validThrough) only, because it only takes the end date. You could also provide [`validFrom`](http://schema.org/validFrom):

```html
<time itemprop="validFrom" datetime="2017-02-18">18 February 2017</time> – <time itemprop="validThrough" datetime="2017-04-20">20 April 2017</time>
```